# Troubleshooting a haskell function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc

I am learning haskell and have some problems understanding what the errors are trying to tell me. This Code produces the following error

```
data Term = Mul { factor :: Term, factor2 :: Term }
          | Div { dividend :: Term, divisor :: Term } 
          | Add { summand :: Term, summand2 :: Term }
          | Sub { minuend :: Term, subtrahend :: Term }
          | Mon { exponent :: Int }

value :: (Double, Term) -> Double
value x (Mul a b) = (value x a) * (value x b)
value x (Div a b) = (value x a) / (value x b)
value x (Add a b) = (value x a) + (value x b)
value x (Sub a b) = (value x a) - (value x b)
value x (Mon a)   = x^a
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Term -> (Double, Term)'
            with actual type `Double'
The function `value' is applied to two arguments,
but its type `(Double, Term) -> Double' has only one
In the first argument of `(+)', namely `(value x a)'
In the expression: (value x a) + (value x b)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your type signature and definitions don't agree on how they are taking the arguments.

You need to either write your type signature in curried style (recommended):

```
value :: Double -> Term -> Double
```

or write your function in uncurried style (non-idiomatic):

```
value (x, Mul a b) = ...
```

I recommend trying both, but the former is almost always the way it is done in the wild.